# Apigility GET doesn't work

Tags: php, api, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

I'm getting another problem in Apigility.

I made a simple service using "db-connected" and it was created nicely.

But when I make a simple GET request to list all of my users, the response is 200 and anything appear in response. But when I make a GET informing an ID it works fine.

Here my service configuration:
[image: Service configuration]

Here my requests that don't work:
[image]
[image: Request]

Here a request working:
[image]

I have no idea what is the problem. 
If someone could help me!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was happen because I had some words with accent in my table data. I solved adding a driver option in database adapter.

It's just add below code in driver:

```
'driver_options' => array(
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES UTF8"
            ),
```

The adapter configuration after changed:

```
'adapters' => array(
        'HookitDsv' => array(
            'database' => '***********',
            'driver' => 'PDO_Mysql',
            'hostname' => '***********',
            'username' => '***********',
            'password' => '***********',
            'driver_options' => array(
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES UTF8"
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

Comment: I think it should throw an exception and not a success without content in request answer.